# why can´t I reinstall nginx?

Tags: nginx

I´ve deinstalled nginx with apt purge nginx. That didn´t delete the nginx folder so I deleted it manually. After apt install nginx again the folder was not recreated so I created it myself and I´ve put the files from the download package inside from nginx webiste. It all didn´t work well so I removed all nginx files and folders. Now when I go to localhost it shows the website: "welcome to nginx" but I have no process running! I can´t find any process with ps aux | grep nginx and also with systemctl status nginx it is not running. Seems I have messed up the VM somehow. I can make a new one and start all over but does anyone know or can explain what is happening here?

Also the apache2 is not running nor in the active process directory.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that there are more related packages, not only the package named exactly `nginx`. For reference https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/nginx

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I´ve done the following:

- uninstalled all packages wich was causing errors while trying to apt upgrade with purge packagename
- then I´ve downloaded the install file from nginx.org and compiled it with ./configure and all the necessary libraries
- I needed to install the compiler first and specify the installation paths
- after compilation I installed it with "make" and then "make install"
- then I added nginx as a service manually with this file https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/systemd/

Now it seems to work and also the folder is there again.

Comment: Sigh. I wouldn't call that a great answer to your original problem. But now that  you have a manually installed nginx version, for which you won't get  any regular security updates from the linux distribution you're using, so you'd better join the mailing list https://mailman.nginx.org/  and not miss out on new releases, security updates and bug fixes

Comment: since it is only for learing purpose I don´t care this much but I don´t know another way. I think it´s best not to delete the nginx folder manually. however since I messed up some configurations I thought I remove and reinstall everything. I didn´t know that this is so complicated in linux.

Comment: You should use nginx build system to create a `dpkg` package of nginx, which will include all the required steps for installing and uninstalling. Building things manually and copying output manually to system directories is a recipie for problems. One needs to know lots of things about the environment to do it safely.